# how to obtain outlook contact group (distribution list )

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007

i'm going to create an add-in for outlook 2007

in this add-in i need to retrieve the list of contact (with all details ) 
in that  group

how can i do that .

Regards ,

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

This is for getting the Details from GAL

```
Outlook.ExchangeUser objExUser=objAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
string FirstName=objExUser.FirstName;
string LastName=objExUser.LastName;
```

This is for getting details from Contacts

```
Outlook.ContactItem objItem= objAddressEntry.GetContact();
string FirstName=objItem.FirstName;
string LastName=objItem.LastName
```